# Combine two DataFrame columns while keeping other columns intact

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   Name  Value_A  Value_B Something_else
0  Bill        5       10         Rabbit
1   Bob        6       11            Cow
```

I want to combine `Value_A` and `Value_B` into a single column, giving me something like this:

```
   Name  Value Something_else
0  Bill      5         Rabbit
1  Bill     10         Rabbit
2   Bob      6            Cow
3   Bob     11            Cow
```

I feel like there is probably a Pandas function to accomplish this, but I can't find it.

My current solution:

```
pd.concat([
    df.rename(columns={"Value_A": "Value"}),
    df.rename(columns={"Value_B": "Value"}),
]).reset_index(drop=True).drop(["Value_A", "Value_B"], axis=1)
```

This gets me the right result (the order is not important):

```
   Name  Value Something_else
0  Bill      5         Rabbit
1   Bob      6            Cow
2  Bill     10         Rabbit
3   Bob     11            Cow
```

But I still think there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `melt`:

```
>>> df.melt(id_vars=["Name","Something_else"], value_vars=["Value_A","Value_B"], value_name="Value").drop(columns="variable")

   Name Something_else  Value
0  Bill         Rabbit      5
1   Bob            Cow      6
2  Bill         Rabbit     10
3   Bob            Cow     11
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `.set_index() + .stack()`:

```py
df = (
    df.set_index(["Name", "Something_else"])
    .stack()
    .droplevel(2)
    .reset_index(name="Value")
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Name Something_else  Value
0  Bill         Rabbit      5
1  Bill         Rabbit     10
2   Bob            Cow      6
3   Bob            Cow     11
```